# How to browse package versions for a particular Ubuntu LTS point release

Tags: package-management, updates, lts, release-management, stable-release-updates

I want to determine which version of a particular package is included in a particular LTS point release.

E.g. I know from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl) that package openssl was at package version 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 when 14.04 was released, and that it's current version (in both the updates and security channels) is 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.16, but I don't know which point release incorporated which new version(s) along the way. E.g. which version did 14.04.1 include?

I see the list of package versions in the openssl trunk series [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/openssl) but I can't find a reliable way to correlate that with the point releases.

This data is obviously out there somewhere; is it discoverable through a GUI or any command line methods?

Comment: Point releases are not real releases. You can easily find which version was in the original 14.04 and what is in the repos now. Why would you need to know which version was in 14.04.1?

Comment: Grab the ISO and read the manifest in it.

Comment: Pilot6 -- We're testing an "appliance" style piece of software. Our clients are likely to be using AWS AMI's, and the like, based on different point releases, and may not be using the latest repo versions of packages. We need to be able to say "we support Ubuntu 14.04 but use point release 3 or later, or the latest updates" if a given package is not at a required version number. Similarly, our installation script tries to install later versions in some cases, or takes other decisions, and we need to know which point releases are relevant cases we need to be testing, etc etc.